# Django model constraint for related objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following code for models:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Activity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='TagBinding')

class TagBinding(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
```

I want to write a database constraint on the `TagBinding` model using a new Django 2.2 syntax. This constraint should check that `tag` and `activity` fields of the `TagBinding` model have the same user. What I've tried to do:

```py
class TagBinding(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name='user_equality',
                check=Q(tag__user=F('activity__user')),
            )
        ]
```

But this doesn't work because Django doesn't allow to use joins inside of the `F` function. Also `Subquery` with `OuterRef` didn't work for me because models that were referenced in a query were not registered.

Is there any way I can implement this constraint using a new syntax without raw SQL?

### Update

It seems like some SQL backends don't support joins in constraints definition, so the question now: is it even possible to implement this behavior in the relational database?

Comment: Why do you need this constraint at the db level?

Comment: Because constraints should be offloaded to the database whenever possible rather than enforcing them in code. But is this constraint necessary? My suspicion is that it could be avoided with different modelling, but I cannot quite put my finger on it.

Comment: @dan-klasson Of course, I can include this logic in the code level, but I would prefer to restrict this behavior on the lowest level possible (especially if this behavior logically fits this level). @EndreBoth I was also looking for another modeling, but haven't found any. All solutions that I came up with were just about removing model `Tag` and define the `tags` field in the `Activity` model. But it removes all additional data that can be stored with a tag.

Comment: There's something wrong with the modeling indeed. You already have ManyToMany field 'tags' in the Activity model. This means that the given Activity can be associated with many Tags and therefore to many different Users (assuming that Tags have different users). The 'user' attribute in the activity doesn't seem to have much sense for me in this case. And if you want to achieve the "binding" then you don't need to manually create a separate table for that (Django already creates it for you behind the scenes for the ManyToMany field).

Comment: @arudzinska The `user` field is required for both models because the relation is not obligatory. There can be activities that have no tags and tags that have no activities, but they both should be assigned to the specific user. The intermediate model `TagBinding` was added to the example because it was used later for the constraint definition. In the case when there is nothing to add to the intermediate model it can be omitted (as you said).

Comment: One thing that stood out: Are you sure about having strictly separate tags and activities for every user, rather than allowing for tags and activities to be associated with several users?

Comment: @EndreBoth Unfortunately, all activities and tags should be assigned to a particular user (no sharing between different users). It is system requirements.

Comment: OK, thanks. One last question: You wrote about "some backends" not supporting joins in constraints. Are you aware of RDBMS that do?

Comment: @EndreBoth According to Wikipedia ("Check constraint" article): "Most database management systems restrict check constraints to a single row, with access to constants and deterministic functions, but not to data in other tables, or to data invisible to the current transaction because of transaction isolation.". For example, some articles state that SQL Server has these restrictions (can't say for sure).

Comment: I still feel this could be solved with a proper db design. How about this: creating User, Tag and Activity models where Tag and Activity *do not* have the 'user' field. They're bare, unassigned at this state. The binding takes place in a separate model that I'll call Group, which has three fields: 'user' (required), 'tag' (optional) and 'activity' (optional). This way if you want to associate Tag and Activity with a specific user, you can check the combinations in the Group table. It also allows you to associate User only to a Tag or only to an Activity.

Comment: What RDBMS are you looking to implement the logic on as that will tell you whether or not its possible at a lower level. I doubt you will achieve what you are after doing out of the box without creating custom SQL in a migration to create whatever is required such as a trigger that fires before insert to check.

Answer (score 7):

In Postgres, there are two types of constraints (other than things like unique and foreign key constraints), CHECK CONSTRAINTS and EXCLUDE constraints.

Check constraints can only apply to a single row.

Exclusion constraints can only apply to a single table.

You will not be able to use either of these to enforce the constraint you want, which crosses table boundaries to ensure consistency.

What you could use instead are trigger-based constraints, that can perform other queries in order to validate the data.

For instance, you could have a BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE trigger on the various tables that checks the users match. I have some similar code that runs on same self-relation tree code that ensures a parent and child both have the same "category" as one another.

In this case, it's going to be a bit trickier, because you would need some mechanism of preventing the check until all tables involved have been updated.