# How to constrain foreign key to field in other foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Sorry for the horrible question title, I'm not sure how to phrase this. Here's a dummy example to make things clear.

If I have models like:

```py
class Shop(models.Model):
    mechanics = models.ManyToManyField(mechanic)

class Mechanic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Car(models.Model):
    problem = models.CharField()
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    fixer = models.ForeignKey(Mechanic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

How do I restrict the model so that `fixer` is always only ever a mechanic in the same shop as the car?

Hopefully this is straight forward, but I've been scouring the Django docs and Stackoverflow and things haven't quite come together.

I've looked into using a `CheckConstraint` on the model, but I'm not sure how to format the query. I've also learned about the `limit_choices_to` of a ForeignKey, but have run into a similar problem. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: How is the mechanic related to the shop? Does mechanic have a FK to the shop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60633653/6550449

Comment: What about model validation? Is it ok for you?